# Printing the Index of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

How do you print the index of an array in Java? 
I'm really stuck with this I feel like it should be something like an if statement like

```
if (i == 5050) {
    System.out.println("Index is: " +i);
}
```

I'd really appreciate any help even if it's just a good place to start searching for the answer. 
Thanks

```
public class summation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] a = new long[101];
        long sum;
        int i, numbers;
        numbers = 100;
        // initialise the array a using the loop counter
        for (i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
            a[i] = (long) i;

        }

        sum = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
            // do summation
            sum = sum + a[i];
        }
        System.out.println("sum of numbers between 1 and " + numbers + " is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to print the index, and what index?  Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Java array indices start at 0. Also, how would a number between 1 and 100 equal 5050?

Comment: I want to print the index of the number 5050, sorry for the lack of clarity. @ElliotFrisch I'm adding the sum of 1-100 which is 5050.

Comment: @System_error that's still utterly unclear.  In an array, the `index` is the term for the bit inside the brackets, e.g. the `i` in `a[i]`.  5050 doesn't appear in the array, so there is no "index".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch 5050 is the sum of 1 .. 100

Comment: @Alnitak thank you I see I was misunderstanding the question I need to answer it was actually "prints out the location of the element in the array that contains the maximum"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `a` array can never contain the number 5050, since you set it to be 1..100 only. May you mean you want to print the the index when the combined sum reaches 50, in which case it'd be

```
    for (i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
        // do summation
        sum = sum + a[i];
        if (sum == 5050) { print code goes here }  
    }
```

And note that there's no point in having two separate loops for this. Why not combine both into a single loop:

```
for (i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
    a[i] = i;
    sum += i;
    if (sum == 5050) { blah blah blah }
}
```

Comment: Ok so is the array actually storing 5050?

Comment: no, you never store anything but the values of `i`, which you've already limited to `1,2,3,...,100`. the `sum` variable CAN contain 5050 at some point, but only one one particular loop iteration, since it's a simple number that you're constantly adding to

Comment: Ok thanks, so the phrase "location of the element in the array that contains the maximum" is actually asking for 100. Sorry for being so slow :)